# Changing properties of a variable in the whole text

Tags: formatting

I am writing a paper and I've been using a lot of variables in my text, but I want to bold all of them. Is there anyway to do it besides using \textbf in each one?

Comment: Could you provide an example of how you are declaring and using your variables?

Comment: I think I'm using the wrong term. It's not a variable in Latex, it is a variable in math way. For example, I'm workinf with a data set X={x_1, x_2,...,x_n}, and I wrote them many times in the paper, but I want them to be bold everytime I wrote them.

Answer (score 1):

When writing 'math' variables like `$x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$` they appear as just text to LaTeX, so there is no way to change their typesetting without using a command on each one.
However, as you might change your opinion on using bold variables later, you could define a custom command

```latex
\newcommand{\var}[1]{{\bm{#1}}}
```

and use that to define your variable `x`:

```latex
\newcommand{\x}{\var{x}}
```

Then you can replace all you `x` variables by `\x`, which looks more readable than `\var{x}` or `\bm{x}` and hopefully avoids any future replace-hells (as you only have to change the `\bm` in the definition of `\var`).

---

Note that `\bm` requires the [bm](https://ctan.org/pkg/bm?lang=en) package.
A complete example:

```latex
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand{\var}[1]{{\bm{#1}}}
\newcommand{\x}{\var{x}}

\begin{document}
    $x \x \x_1$
\end{document}
```